# How to debug PyQt crashes?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qprocess

I am developing a chess program where the GUI communicates with the engine via the [UCI protocol](http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html), currently using OSX and PyCharm. I am using a QProcess to communicate.

My app crashes, but I cannot deterministically reproduce those crashes. Python output just gives

```
Process finished with exit code 134
```

The crash report on OSX gives this detailed report, but to be honest I am completely lost on how to get any further. I suspect some issues with threading, but how to debug?

```
Process:         Python [527]
Path:            /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      org.python.python
Version:         3.4.1 (3.4.1)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  pycharm [360]
Responsible:     pycharm [360]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2015-02-16 10:40:09.497 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  XXXXXX


Crashed Thread:  4  Uci_engine

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
*** error for object 0x7fb104975000: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated


Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   QtCore                          0x0000000109475d2e QByteArray::resize(int) + 6
1   QtCore                          0x00000001094ec5e9 QRingBuffer::clear() + 123
2   QtCore                          0x00000001094f58ab QProcess::readData(char*, long long) + 257
3   QtCore.so                       0x000000010a081784 sipQProcess::readData(char*, long long) + 106
4   QtCore                          0x00000001094f0648 QIODevice::read(char*, long long) + 828
5   QtCore                          0x00000001094f0a92 QIODevice::readAll() + 398
6   QtCore                          0x00000001094f59a6 QProcess::readAllStandardOutput() + 48
7   QtCore.so                       0x000000010a082b78 meth_QProcess_readAllStandardOutput(_object*, _object*) + 120
8   org.python.python               0x0000000107cbad5c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19156
9   org.python.python               0x0000000107cb60d4 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1628
10  org.python.python               0x0000000107c490b8 function_call + 360
11  org.python.python               0x0000000107c2be11 PyObject_Call + 103
12  org.python.python               0x0000000107c3a8a4 method_call + 136
13  org.python.python               0x0000000107c2be11 PyObject_Call + 103
14  org.python.python               0x0000000107cbdb30 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 93
15  sip.so                          0x00000001097bfd68 sip_api_invoke_slot_ex + 435
16  QtCore.so                       0x000000010a0f5cb0 PyQtProxy::invokeSlot(qpycore_slot const&, void**, int) + 162
17  QtCore.so                       0x000000010a0f5b7c PyQtProxy::unislot(void**) + 184
18  QtCore.so                       0x000000010a0f5ab3 PyQtProxy::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) + 111
19  QtCore                          0x000000010956222d QObject::event(QEvent*) + 637
20  QtGui                           0x0000000108985ed5 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 195
21  QtGui                           0x0000000108987419 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 889
22  QtGui.so                        0x000000010811a29a sipQApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 122
23  QtCore                          0x0000000109551bb8 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) + 118
24  QtCore                          0x000000010955259c QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) + 716
25  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff904985b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
26  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90489c62 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
27  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff904893ef __CFRunLoopRun + 831
28  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90488e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
29  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff87427a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
30  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff87427685 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 173
31  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff874275bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87e5724e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87e5689b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
34  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87e4a99c -[NSApplication run] + 553
35  QtGui                           0x0000000108943936 QEventDispatcherMac::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 540
36  QtCore                          0x000000010954f215 QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 77
37  QtCore                          0x000000010954f386 QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 356
38  QtCore                          0x0000000109552009 QCoreApplication::exec() + 199
39  QtGui.so                        0x000000010811b4eb meth_QApplication_exec_(_object*, _object*) + 80
40  org.python.python               0x0000000107cbad5c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19156
41  org.python.python               0x0000000107cb60d4 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1628
42  org.python.python               0x0000000107cb5a72 PyEval_EvalCode + 63
43  org.python.python               0x0000000107cd9b28 run_mod + 58
44  org.python.python               0x0000000107cd9dc7 PyRun_FileExFlags + 178
45  org.python.python               0x0000000107cd95e7 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 909
46  org.python.python               0x0000000107cec4f7 Py_Main + 3095
47  org.python.python               0x0000000107c19e27 0x107c18000 + 7719
48  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff87a165fd start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e18f662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff86c6f421 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff86c6f136 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e18aa1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e189d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90489f15 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90489539 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90488e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87ff705e _NSEventThread + 144
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c7a2899 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c7a272a _pthread_start + 137
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c7a6fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: QProcessManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e18e9aa __select + 10
1   QtCore                          0x000000010952cf86 QProcessManager::run() + 132
2   QtCore                          0x00000001094735ba QThreadPrivate::start(void*) + 386
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c7a2899 _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c7a272a _pthread_start + 137
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c7a6fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 4 Crashed:: Uci_engine
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e18e866 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c7a335c pthread_kill + 92
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91b34b1a abort + 125
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff876b5451 realloc + 364
4   QtCore                          0x00000001094762dd QByteArray::realloc(int) + 161
5   QtCore                          0x0000000109475d88 QByteArray::resize(int) + 96
6   QtCore                          0x00000001094ec6c1 QRingBuffer::reserve(int) + 157
7   QtCore                          0x00000001094f41ec QProcessPrivate::_q_canReadStandardOutput() + 76
8   QtCore                          0x00000001094f65ce QProcess::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) + 364
9   QtCore                          0x0000000109565d71 QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) + 2037
10  QtCore                          0x00000001095a7b68 QSocketNotifier::activated(int) + 60
11  QtCore                          0x000000010956a421 QSocketNotifier::event(QEvent*) + 383
12  QtGui                           0x0000000108985ed5 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 195
13  QtGui                           0x0000000108987419 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 889
14  QtGui.so                        0x000000010811a29a sipQApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 122
15  QtCore                          0x0000000109551bb8 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) + 118
16  QtCore                          0x0000000109579db7 QEventDispatcherUNIX::activateSocketNotifiers() + 203
17  QtCore                          0x0000000109579b8e QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate::doSelect(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>, timeval*) + 1426
18  QtCore                          0x000000010957ae39 QEventDispatcherUNIX::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 341
19  QtCore                          0x000000010954f215 QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 77
20  QtCore                          0x000000010954f386 QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 356
21  QtCore                          0x0000000109471ca5 QThread::exec() + 217
22  QtCore.so                       0x000000010a0c28f3 meth_QThread_exec_(_object*, _object*) + 99
23  org.python.python               0x0000000107cbad5c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19156
24  org.python.python               0x0000000107cb60d4 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1628
25  org.python.python               0x0000000107c490b8 function_call + 360
26  org.python.python               0x0000000107c2be11 PyObject_Call + 103
27  org.python.python               0x0000000107c3a8a4 method_call + 136
28  org.python.python               0x0000000107c2be11 PyObject_Call + 103
29  org.python.python               0x0000000107cbdb30 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 93
30  sip.so                          0x00000001097b6559 sip_api_call_method + 214
31  QtCore.so                       0x000000010a002174 sipVH_QtCore_11(PyGILState_STATE, void (*)(_sipSimpleWrapper*, PyGILState_STATE), _sipSimpleWrapper*, _object*) + 47
32  QtCore.so                       0x000000010a0c24fb sipQThread::run() + 79
33  QtCore                          0x00000001094735ba QThreadPrivate::start(void*) + 386
34  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c7a2899 _pthread_body + 138
35  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c7a272a _pthread_start + 137
36  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c7a6fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e18ee6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c7a3f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c7a6fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x000000010a84d000  rcx: 0x000000010a84bd98  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000002f1f  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x000000010a84bdc0  rsp: 0x000000010a84bd98
   r8: 0x00000000fffffff8   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fb104975000  r13: 0x0000000000000004  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000107c1e000
  rip: 0x00007fff8e18e866  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff784a0408

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

Comment: Step 1 would be to make sure you aren't doing anything with the Qt GUI from threads. That is the most common cause of crashes and is easy to check for. Just follow through all the code in your thread(s) and see if you access any of the GUI.

Comment: thanks for that hint; however I exclusively use queued signals and slots for that communication. So that _should_ be fine...

Comment: I have had issues in the past where, despite specifying queued connections, they weren't. But that said, I typically use Python threads over QThreads so don't have a huge amount of experience. Looks like you worked around tour issue anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this thread crashed.

```
Thread 4 Crashed:: Uci_engine
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e18e866 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c7a335c pthread_kill + 92
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91b34b1a abort + 125
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff876b5451 realloc + 364
4   QtCore                          0x00000001094762dd QByteArray::realloc(int) + 161
```

This thread crashed caused the whole program crashed and exit.

From the stacks, it looks like memory access got exception, usually this kind of debugging is difficult for python, for PyQt, it is more complicated. it requires you know a lot of cpython and it's implementation, besides you should know the implementation of Qt and Sip, as Cpython has GC, so it is more complicated. In my view, if this could be reproduced, then try to add more log to find out which lines of code caused this issue. If this happen occasionally and usually during the Qt exit time, then you should elegantly set the inherit tree.

Besides, which version of pycharm are you using?  The newest PyCharm 4.* will automatically hook the python executable program during debug time,  I have find out that sometimes it crashes during debug time for complicated PyQt project but OK if just run without debug, if this only happens at "debug" the program, you could try to switch to earlier pycharm or just disable this auto-hook feature.

Comment: thx for your advice, but in the end I gave up. I tried various stuff, even switching off garbage collection in order to try to understand where the issue is.
What works now: I rewrote parts of my program in such a way, that I could get away by using QProcess + signals&slots to handle the external call of the engine.
Just a word of warning to everyone: QThread is just probably quite buggy and better to be avoided. Even if it's bug free (which I do not think) it's incredible difficult to issue multithreaded programs under Python + Qt; just stay away from QThread and use QProcess instead.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that this was caused at certain point of QThread, I used Pycharm, it seems pycharm could not debug the QThread, but OK for general python built-in thread, so I guess possibly QThread is using SIP to create real-native Thread(I am not sure about this, just guess). If it is using native thread, could that be caused overflow local thread stack? for QThread, I usually use it in a sync call way, if everything works fine, then use Queue as the message Queue to pass argument to the QThread.

Comment: QThread indeed relies on sip. I was unable to debug that with PyCharm. I did use a (supposedly) thread-safe queue to pass messages around. Still crashed randomly - as said, QThread is better to be avoided.... :-(